# Uploaded Image Is Null Laravel and I am getting this error file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I was trying to convert the image uploaded into a form into base 64 in Laravel but the uploaded image is null

Blade File-->(View)

```
<body>
   
    <form action="{{Route('PostImageProcess')}}" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{-- {!! Form::label($for, $text, [$options]) !!} --}}
            <label for="img">post Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="img">
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Inside Controller-->

```
public function PostImageProcess(Request $request){

    // $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
    

    $ima= base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
    echo $ima;
    
    $image="11221";
    
   
    return view('afterPostSuccess')->with("body",$image);
    
}
```

and I am getting this error: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: You only have a uploaded file at this point, file_get_contents needs a path to where the file is stored. I do not know if there is another way to skip persisting the file first, but that is your issue. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: make a validator before that

Comment: Its uploaded image from Form how can I specify the path

Comment: You need the uploaded image name ?

Comment: I did not get you @STA I am using name attribute of file type and its a uploaded image from Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not validating your `Request $request`

```
        $valid = $request->validate([
                     'image' => 'required|max:100024',
                ]);

         $ima= base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')));
         echo $ima;

          $image="11221";
          return view('afterPostSuccess')->with("body",$image);
```

**UPDATE**

Edit your form like:

```
  <body>
     <form method="post" action="{{Route('PostImageProcess')}}" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
       {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
          {{-- {!! Form::label($for, $text, [$options]) !!} --}}
          <label for="img">post Image</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="img">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: if you `dd($request->file('image') )`, you got the image or is empty?

Comment: using dd($request->file('image')) is also giving null

Comment: Add method="POST" in your form declarion.

Comment: I updated the answer to include how you should declare the form

Comment: Bro thanks I neglected this thing as i was doing every thing in controller thanks bro i was stuck in this error from morning

Comment: Great. Sometimes it happens to focus on the wrong side. Glad I helped